# Values from multidimensional to array

Tags: php, arrays

array fetched somewhere else:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 600000
            [name] => test1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 600300
            [name] => test2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 600600
            [name] => test3
        )
)
```

php:

```
$leftnav = array("root_id" => 0, "sub_id" => 0, "subsub_id" => 0, "subsubsub_id" => 0);

if (isset($category_data[0]['id']))
$leftnav['root_id'] = $category_data[0]['id'];

if (isset($category_data[1]['id']))
$leftnav['sub_id'] = $category_data[1]['id'];

if (isset($category_data[2]['id']))
$leftnav['subsub_id'] = $category_data[2]['id'];

if (isset($category_data[3]['id']))
$leftnav['subsubsub_id'] = $category_data[3]['id'];
```

Can the php code be done in a more pretty way? I have tried with array_map but all required keys in $leftnav will not be set.

Comment: Could you please explain more clearly what you want and what part of your code doesn't work? I really don't want to try to decipher what your code is doing.

Comment: @DennisHaarbrink from what I understand it works. He just wants a more efficiënt and clean code.

Comment: Yes it works, just want to see if it could be optimzed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$i = 0;
foreach( $leftnav as $k => $v ) {
    if ( isset($category_data[$i]['id']) ) {
        $leftnav[$k] = $category_data[$i]['id'];
    }
    $i++;
}
```